# Get all managed file usage by id

Tags: 7, files

Is there a way to get all the managed files used by a particular entity, i.e. a node or other module item?

Looking in the file_usage table there is an `id` column and this is what I want to retrieve fid's by.

Seems like something that there would be a function for, but I haven't found it yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function. However it's not hard to create your own. Here's an example:

```
function load_files_by_type($type, $id) {
  // Select all used files by type and id.
  $query = db_select('file_usage', 'fu')
    ->fields('fu', array('fid'))
    ->condition('fu.type', $type)
    ->condition('fu.id', $id);

  // Load all file ids in an array.
  $fids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

  // Return the file objects.
  return file_load_multiple($fids);
}
```

You can call it like this: `load_files_by_type('node', 64);`

Of course you can alter the query to your liking, you could even add a module check.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'll accept your answer if no one else chimes in with a specific Drupal function based approach.
Seems weird that there isn't - I'm not sure I understand what the file_usage table is for if not this kind of thing...

Comment: Naturally, I'm curious myself if such a function exists.

Comment: Still there is no such function in drupal 8 also? If so, it's weird. If there is any such function added, can someone post here.